# Can I create a service that plugs directly to my controller or maybe component

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I may be wrong, but I was under the impression that I could access my service and have it display the data directly.

I.e. I can inject my service and have read/write access to it from multiple components, Its easy enough to do, but if I want the services data to be displayed, I need to copy it to the controller to let $scope/vm/this to then hook it into the HTML template. but that means any changes that happen at the DOM level, need to be watched/triggered to tell the service that it changed, Which I'd like to be automatic.

I'm essentially trying to save time asking if it can be done, Its something I've been curious about, has anyone set it up before and got it working? Would you be so kind as to elaborate?

Comment: Can you create an example fiddle to show us what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

At this case, you can create service as you always do, but then assign it to `$rootScope` property(for example `service`) at `run` method, so you can use it via `service.name` or `service.test` literals at your templates without restrictions, because all `$scope`s are inherited from `$rootScope`. Also you not need to inject service to your particular controller, you can use it at once via template:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('myservice', function(){  
  return {
    test: function(){
      console.log(this.name);
    },
    name: 'Tom'
  };
}).controller('ctrl', function($scope, myservice){  
  $scope.local = 'from local ctrl';  
  $scope.serviceName = function(){
    return myservice.name;
  }
})

app.run(function(myservice, $rootScope){
  $rootScope.service = myservice;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='service.name'/> 
  {{serviceName()}}
  <br>
  <input type='button' ng-click='service.test()' value='service.test'/>  
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type='text' ng-model='local'/>  
<div>
```

Comment: This indeed looks like it does what I wanted to know, my only concern is that you use rootscope, and I was under the impression that we should not use rootscope, under any circumstances. no?

Comment: @BaneStar007, If you admit behavior, described at your question, you should not concern about `$rootScope` at all.

Comment: So if I translate what I think your saying, then what I'm asking is code smell(bad practices), therefore your solution is acceptable that it uses bad practices too?

Comment: @BaneStar007 No, _"bad"_ or _"good"_ practice is very subjective concept and at this case I can't assert anything, because, at least, I doesn't have full information and requirements for your application. May be your desired behavior and my solution smell, may be not and they are exactly, what you need, you shoud determine this fact by yourself. Your requirement is enough unique, but probably is necessary, so using of `$rootScope` may be justified at this case.